# TensorFlow: while learning parameters getting NAN

Tags: python, arrays, machine-learning, tensorflow

am trying simple linear reg gradient descent sample below is my code ...

```
def gardientDecent(features,target):
     alpha = tf.constant(0.001,dtype=tf.float64)
     length = tf.cast(tf.size(target),dtype=tf.float64)
     feature_one = features[:,0]
     features_Val = tf.transpose(features)

     dummy_theta = tf.zeros([2,1],dtype=tf.float64)

     dot_product = tf.multiply(features_Val, dummy_theta)
     diff = tf.subtract(dot_product, target)
     diff_one = tf.multiply(diff, feature_one)

     theta1 = tf.reduce_sum(diff)
     theta2 = tf.reduce_sum(diff_one)

     final1 = tf.div(theta1, length)
     final2 = tf.div(theta2, length)

     t1 = tf.subtract(theta1, tf.multiply(alpha, final1))
     t2 = tf.subtract(theta2, tf.multiply(alpha, final2))

     newArray = np.array([[0],[0]],dtype=np.float64)
     for i in range(1000):
            temp1,temp2 = vas.run([t1,t2],{dummy_theta:newArray})
            print i ,temp1,temp2
            newArray = np.array([[temp1],[temp2]],dtype=np.float64)
     print vas.run(tf.cast(newArray,dtype=tf.float64))
```

but while running after few steps am getting Nan values like this ...

[image]

pls help me out ....am new to both ML and Tensor flow...TY in advance

Comment: Please don't post images of code, they can't be copy-pasted and are hard to read. Edit your post.

Comment: @gionni modified now

Answer (score 0):

It seems like it is the loss that you subtract from your parameters, instead of the actual gradient of that loss with respect to theta. You should call `grad1 = tf.gradients(tf.reduce_sum(diff), theta1)` same for `theta2` (with `diff_one`) and then subtract that (with the alpha weight) from `theta1` and `theta2`: `t1 = tf.subtract(theta1, tf.multiply(alpha, grad1))` and same for `theta2`